# when i am cloning in to website it shows error

Tags: ssh, git

```
git clone http://sample.com/bag name
```

here i mentioned web address as `sample.com/bag` for reference.

I also tried with `ssh://sample.com/bag name`

I also tried with     `ssh://git@sample.com/bag name`

when i entered password for git@sample.com/bag name :
it shows permission denied,please try again
 password for git@sample.com/bag name :
it shows permission denied,please try again
 password for git@sample.com/bag name :
it shows (public key,password)

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: ***recheck the link***.git will show password error even if link is incorrect.I have experienced it before while cloning repo from `github`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http protocol requires the git server to support smart http. Not all git servers support this. Also, some sites that are set up with smart http support only https (HTTP over SSL). The remote git server might also not allow cloning for some reason. You should probably talk to the person who maintains the remote git repo.

Answer (score 0):

try cloning without using ssh, try with http. It might help you.

Comment: I tried with  http,ssh & git.

Comment: Are you trying to deal with mediawiki related issues?